# Angular Directive to make row clickable link, having issues with navigation condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, svg

I have an angular directive to make an HTML element act as if it was a link. It does that just fine. My issue is getting it to quit that behavior under certain circumstances, namely, when the user clicks a child `<button>` element of the decorated element. I have it behaving correctly, but REALLY don't like the way I'm doing things. I'm hoping to find a cleaner, more reliable solution.

I have the following Angular directive to make a row act act as a link

It's pretty simple. Takes a url string, has some event listeners, delegates most of its brains to a service. For the sake a brevity, I will show only the critical parts of the `GoToService`.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appGoto]'
})
export class GotoDirective {

  @Input() appGoto: string;

  constructor(private _goToSvc: GoToService) {
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  OnEvent($event) {
    this._goToSvc.goTo(this.appGoto, $event);
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  OnMouseDown($event) {
    this._goToSvc.markMouseDownLocation($event);
  }

}
```

Here is my current solution. it's ugly, but I'll explain why I have it so. It takes an event, and its target, checks if the event's target is a button (naive approach first). If that fails, it then checks to see if the event's click coordinates intersect with **some** button in the DOM. I agree, blegh.

```
 private _isButtonOrIntersectsWithButton(target, $event): boolean {
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
      return true;
    }

    const xCoordinate = $event.x;
    const yCoordinate = $event.y;

    const buttons = this._document.getElementsByTagName('button');

    // array functions (ie .some(v => ...) don't work on htmlelement collections, using manual loop
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
    for (let iButton = 0; iButton < buttons.length; iButton++) {
      const button = buttons[iButton] as HTMLElement;
      const boundary = button.getBoundingClientRect();
      const xRange = [boundary.left < boundary.right ? boundary.left : boundary.right
        , boundary.right > boundary.left ? boundary.right : boundary.left];
      const yRange = [boundary.bottom < boundary.top ? boundary.bottom : boundary.top
        , boundary.top > boundary.bottom ? boundary.top : boundary.bottom];

      if (xCoordinate >= xRange[0] && xCoordinate <= xRange[1] &&
        yCoordinate >= yRange[0] && yCoordinate <= yRange[1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Originally, I had implemented a simple recursive parent graph traversal. Something along the lines of the following pseudocode

```
func isElementButtonOrChildThereof
   if element is button
      return true
   if element is not button
      go get its parent

   if parent is null
      return false

   recurse on parent, default to false if stack gets too deep
```

The issue with that solution however, was SVGs. We use `FontAwesome` and have some icons in our buttons as `<fa-icon>`s. These in turn have `<svg>` elements which contain `<path>` elements. For some reason, `SVGSVGElement`s seem to have no notion of their parent. Which is odd, because it appears their child `SVGPathElements` do. If the target of the event was an `<svg>`, or its child `<path>`, then the graph traversal would die prematurely and conclude that the element is not a button or a child of a button.

I have also tried explicitly passing elements I want ignored to the directive and checked my target against them and all their children. The issue with that was the `===` operator, while fine for most HTML elements, fell flat when it came to comparing `<svg>` and `<path>` elements. I.E., an `<svg>`  target when compared to an equivalent `<svg>` would return false. The same with `<path>` elements.

For now, the cludgy collision code works but I don't like it. I'm looking for better alternatives.